# Git - Ignore Removal

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

Long story short, I have a Laravel 4 project with a folder full of migrations. I am unsure whether the migrations are actually consistent with the current state of the database, and so is my client, who therefore instructed me not to write migrations for the database changes I have to make, but instead to just make them. I want to make the changes I do to the database migratable, at least from and to the current state.

So, I added the migration for my change, and moved all existing migrations out of the *migrations* folder. This way, I can run `migrate` and `migrate:rollback` to test only my migrations. Which works fine. But I don't want to remove the existing migrations *from the repo*, because they need to be there to cater for the slim chance that they are consistent with the current state. What troubles me is that they show up in Git all the time, and I want them out of the way. The end result would be that my *migrations* folder would contain only the migrations I write for this job, *for the duration of this job*, but the repository would eventually contain all the migrations.

What would be the best way to get the existing files out of Git's way, while still giving me what I want?

Alternatively, perhaps there is a better way to test only my migrations?

Thanks!

Comment: You can simply create a folder (let's say `new`) in the `migrations` directory, where you can create your new migration classes, then when running the migrations you can pass that path to the command like so: `php artisan migrate --path=app/database/migrations/new`. This way you're leaving the existing migrations in place, and you can work with your own migrations separately.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, leave the migrations folder alone, create a another folder for your migrations, something like `app/foo/migrations` and add the exact same path folder to your `.gitignore`.

The whenever you need to run your migrations just run this:

```
php artisan migrate --path=app/foo/migrations
```

You can read more about it in the [Laravel Documentation about migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#running-migrations)